# Accidentally removed my "Documents" from my "Libraries"

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-management, libraries

By mistake I removed the my "Documents" folder from my "Libraries" The folder still exist however under `C:\Users\user\Documents`, I didn't delete any files. How can I restore the my "Documents back to the "Libraries" folder?

[image]

I tried creating a new library and then importing the folder, but it is not the same as it was before.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/x5zNuwF.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried right-clicking on 'Libraries' and selecting 'Restore default' (I think the option is under Windows) yet?

This may resolve the library name even if it does not return the content.  This could be moved manually after the fact, if necessary, I'm sure.

Comment: Why must a solution be so simple. I feel stupid. Thank for the answer. :)

Comment: All solutions should be this simple. :)  I'm glad it worked, though!